# How to construct an SQL query for RDOMail.Find in Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook-redemption

I am trying to use RDOMail.Find to check whether an email exists in a public folder (I am coding in Delphi).

The problem I have is that I cannot get even the most basic query to return any items.  For example, the following query does not return any results, even when I know that there are emails in the folder that have that the specified subject:-

```
ExistingRDOItem := ExistingRDOFolderItems.Find('SELECT Subject FROM Folder WHERE Subject = ' + QuotedStr(NewRDOItem.Subject);
```

Can anyone explain to me why my query does not work / what I need to do to fix it?

I obviously want to construct a more complex query than this, but I need to get the basics right first!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of Outlook no longer index `PR_SUBJECT` property, you need to search on `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT` (that is, the subject without a prefix). Also, you don't need to pass SELECT clause and WHERE statement, just the search clause is enough:

```
PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"
value = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT)

  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  set Items = Inbox.Items
  set item = Items.Find("""" & PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT & """ = '" & value & "'")
  while Not (item Is Nothing)
    Debug.Print item.Subject
    set item = Items.FindNext
  wend
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But are you able to translate that into Delphi for me?  There are an awful lot of quotation marks in there!

Comment: Sure: `query := ' "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F" = ' + QuotedStr(somevar);`

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks very much.